# convert padded topics address to valid address string

Tags: web3js, addresses, events, nodejs, logs

I am parsing some information from the topics array.

I receive 32bit padded addresses in some indexes. Is there a web3 utility function or useful helper method to get these back into normal sized addresses?

I'm not sure if I will remove the correct amount of 0's to get the same valid address Im looking for.

Please advise

Comment: Did you finaly find a way ?

Comment: @Lbrth_BoC I think I do something similar to the answer below, and then run the web3 isValid method to double check

Answer (score 7):

A bit simpler:

```js
function paddedToChecksumAddress(address) {
  if (address.slice(0, 2) === '0x') address = address.slice(2)
  while (address.slice(0, 2) === '00') address = address.slice(2)
  return web3.utils.toChecksumAddress('0x' + address)
}
```

Edit:

```js
web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('address', address)
```

is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Try this for any length of padding:

```
    getAddress(address) {
        const web3Utils = require('web3-utils');

        let i = -1;
        let exit = false;
        let result = address;
        while(!exit && i < address.length){
            i++;
            result = "0x" + address.substring(i);
            exit = web3Utils.isAddress(result);
        }

        return web3Utils.toChecksumAddress(result);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This function removes any leading groups of "00", and then adds "0x" at the beginning.

```
public string AddressWithoutPadding(string address)
    {
        if (address.StartsWith("0x"))
            address = address.Remove(0, 2);
        do
        {
            if (address.StartsWith("00"))
            {
                address = address.Remove(0, 2);
            }
            else
                break;
        } while (true);
        return "0x" + address;
    }
```